# Facebook Graph API Authentication for Comment Count? (Think I'm missing something.)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm having a bit of an issue trying to get some PHP code to work with the Open Graph API provided by Facebook.

I have some PHP code that takes a url and returns the number of comments on that page that were made using the Facebook Comments plugin.

I know the code works, however, there is a small problem.

When I try my code, it doesn't show any information. When I check in the API Explorer provided by Facebook, the information I want is there. The only difference is that when using the API explorer an Access Token is being used.

The code I'm running is trying to get the Graph data for pages on the same domain. This is not something that requires the person to authorize our application either, as it makes no sense to ask for authorization just to tell someone how many comments have been made on a page.

So my question is, how do I include an access token in the code below:

```
function fb_comment_count($url = '') {
$filecontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
$json = json_decode($filecontent);
$count = $json->$url->comments;
if ($count == 0 || !isset($count)) {
    $count = 0;
}
echo $count;
}
```

Right now the only problem is with this **https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url** it is returning empty, but the API Explorer shows the proper information when I use the same URL. Can an Access Token be included in this somewhere, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm using PHP on my site to access Graph information on the same site. This should work without anyone having to authorize this. If there is some one-time authorization that I can do, that's fine.

Comment: Can you share the link or call to the API explorer that you are making.

Comment: The URL I am checking in the API Explorer is "https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://news.essentialtransit.com/2012020434-St.+John-27s+preps+plans+for+-2410M+windfall.html" When I select my application in the list it changes the Access Token that is used. It also says this in the response: '"comments": 1,'. That is the info I need my script to be able to access, however without including the Access Code somehow this information is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up using this code, which allow me to get more than just comment counts (it uses the Facebook PHP SDK):

```
<?php
// Stats taken from link_stats table
// Documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/
function FBLinkStats($url,$type){

$fbconfig['appid' ]  = "###########";
$fbconfig['secret']  = "###########";
include_once "facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid' ],
    'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
    'cookie' => true
));

$fql = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = '".$url."' ";
$param  =   array(
    'method'    => 'fql.query',
    'query'     => $fql,
    'callback'  => ''
);
$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
return $fqlResult[0][$type];
}
?>
```

The function takes two variables, the URL of the page you are fetching information on, and the stat you want returned, which can be found on this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/

Comment: I am not sure about this but isn't Facebook outdating FBML or FQL?

Comment: On some of the older Facebook documentation there is a notice at the top saying it is either depreciated, or will be depreciated in the future. However, on the FQL documentation page there is no such message, so I'm hoping that it is not something they plan on ending anytime soon.

Comment: fb is depreciating public access, so this is a good way to go (read: future access might require appid.)

Answer (score 1):

You need an access token to query for this data.

However, rather than asking a user to authenticate, you can use an app access token.

See how to generate one here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

Comment: Thanks, I missed this page when I was looking through things. I decided to go with a FQL method to get the data I was looking for. However, I am going to vote your answer up because this information was useful.